# Sending an email to all emails in a loop firebase cloud function

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created a cloud function that goes into a firebase collection called 'properties' and then into a sub-collection within a specific property called 'mid_tenancy'. Within the id of the 'mid_tenancy' I then loop through each member of the tenancy and access their email.

The problem I am having however, is that the email is only sent out to the first email in the loop and not any of the others. This is how my database looks:

[image]

**I have removed the emails for obvious reasons**

and this is my cloud function:

```
export const midTenancyEmail = functions.firestore
    .document('properties/{propertyId}/mid_tenancy/{midTenancyId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const propertyId = event.params.propertyId;
        const midTenancyId = event.params.midTenancyId;
        const db = admin.firestore();
        const propertyDoc = db.collection('properties').doc(propertyId);
        const midTenancyDoc = propertyDoc.collection('mid_tenancy').doc(midTenancyId);
        let mid_tenancy;

        return propertyDoc
            .get()
            .then(doc => {
                const property = doc.data();
                midTenancyDoc.get().then(data => {
                    mid_tenancy = data.data();
                  for(let tenant of mid_tenancy.mid_tenants) {
                    let msg = {
                        to: tenant.mid_tenant_email,
                        from: 'email',
                        // custom templates
                        subject: 'You have a new direct message',
                        templateId: 'id',
                        substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
                        substitutions: {
                            name: tenant.mid_tenant_name,
                            message: tenant.status,
                        }
                    };
                    return sgMail.send(msg);
                  }
                })
            })
            .then(email => {
                console.log('email sent: ', email);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            })

    });
```

Anyone know why this is only sending out one email? Instead of all the emails within the loop? There seems to be something breaking the loop after the first loop.

Before the loop I have done: `console.log(mid_tenancy.mid_tenants[1].mid_tenant_name` just to be sure it was accessible, and it did log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to push every email task into an array of promises then you return all promises `return Promise.all(promises)`:

```
export const midTenancyEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('properties/{propertyId}/mid_tenancy/{midTenancyId}')
  .onCreate(event => {
    const propertyId = event.params.propertyId;
    const midTenancyId = event.params.midTenancyId;
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const propertyDoc = db.collection('properties').doc(propertyId);
    const midTenancyDoc = propertyDoc.collection('mid_tenancy').doc(midTenancyId);
    let mid_tenancy;
    return propertyDoc
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        const property = doc.data();
        midTenancyDoc.get().then(data => {
          mid_tenancy = data.data();
          const promises = [];
          for (let tenant of mid_tenancy.mid_tenants) {
            let msg = {
              to: tenant.mid_tenant_email,
              from: 'email',
              // custom templates
              subject: 'You have a new direct message',
              templateId: 'id',
              substitutionWrappers: ['{{', '}}'],
              substitutions: {
                name: tenant.mid_tenant_name,
                message: tenant.status,
              }
            };
            promises.push(sgMail.send(msg)) ;
          }
          return Promise.all(promises);
        });
        return null;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You return in the for loop, at the end of the first iteration

```
return sgMail.send(msg);
```

This causes the for loop to stop iterating.

Comment: if i move the return outside of the loop it get an error returns

Comment: @d.mares showed an example in the answer below showing how to properly return all promises